# Can I hide Flutter app contents when the app is in Background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm developing an app that works with sensitive information.

One of the requirements is that when a user puts the app in background the content that the app is currently displaying has to be hidden, so if another person navigate through the apps in background he can't see the last screen where the user was.

Any ideas on how to do that?

I tried to show an overlay when the app moves to `AppLifecycleState.paused`, but it doesn't work for me, the app prints a message if I want but it can't update the UI.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using WidgetBindingObserve?

Comment: Yes, and I override the didChangeAppLifecycleState method.

Comment: And in that you cleared the state or navigated to another screen?

Comment: `case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        setState(() {
          appInBackground = true;
        });
        break;`

Comment: The overlay idea comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069641/how-to-overlay-a-widget-on-top-of-a-flutter-app

Comment: Well, now I know that you are not the only one facing this issue. And the android docs say that for this functionality resort to native code as much as possible. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33236 https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-listen-to-android-activity-lifecycle-events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**
Shameless plug: i did a library for doing just that as I also needed it:

https://pub.dev/packages/secure_application

**Answear**

Build is not called after paused, at least on Android.

For Android I used a flutter_windowmanager package (modified to still be able to build on IOS):

https://github.com/neckaros/flutter_windowmanager

When my app need securing I add the flag secure:

```
FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE)
```

And my app is now a black screen in the app switcher.
You should still hide content your way for when the user get back to the app.

Otherwise you can go native:
https://medium.com/@mehmetf_71205/securing-flutter-apps-ada13e806a69

Comment: I tried you package but it has unfortunately no effect on my Samsung Galaxy M51 (Android 12). I suspect the OS to take a screenshot of my app before putting it in background. Any idea?