# Replace only children when calling Navigator.of(context).push()

Tags: flutter

I am creating a Picture in Picture Widget and I render two screens, one that is floating and the other that stays in the background (both are Scaffolds). When I use `Navigator.of(context).push()` I would like to have replaced only the background view. The current behavior I get, is a screen is pushed over both screens. Is there any way to create a subnavigator? I was thinking about something that could be used like this:

```
Navigator(
  child: MyWidget(),
)
```

And after doing this when I called `Navigator.of(context)` this navigator would be returned and this navigator would only replace children widgets.

For better understanding of what I am talking about I made a video about the current behavior I am getting:

https://youtu.be/L4V4bcZAppI

Comment: I created a package for this component: https://pub.dev/packages/pip_view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking for other keyword, `Overlay` instead of `SubNavigator`, I found the answer to my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57073347/8633918

What I asked for exists but instead of calling the attribute child, it is called onGenerateRoute, and is a bit more complex. Here is how you use it:

```
Navigator(
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MyWidget());
  }
)
```

Here is a video with the expected behaviour:

https://youtu.be/CZ9pFHsARdw