# How to overlay a widget on top of MaterialApp navigator in a flutter App?

Tags: flutter, navigator

Motivation:
In case of internet connectivity loss I want to show a widget which informs the user on connectivity issues.
I want this widget to show when connectivity status changes, **no matter which route is present right now.**

The issue is that I can't find a way to overlay this "connectivity loss" widget on top of the **main navigator** (which comes with the materialApp) class.

What's the best way to implement it?

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069641/how-to-overlay-a-widget-on-top-of-a-flutter-app) but the solution doesn't seems to be optimal...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overlay a widget on top of a flutter App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069641/how-to-overlay-a-widget-on-top-of-a-flutter-app)

Comment: I referred to this in my question, looking for a more built-in mechanism if available

Comment: *"What's the best way to implement it?"* - in most cases `SnackBar` is used for that

Comment: but then again - u'll have to implement this logic in every screen, and I'm trying to implement it in a single place, some kind of a "root" object of the flutter app