# How to overlay a widget on top of a Flutter app with named routes?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app (Android and iOS only), I want to add a widget that will overlay the entire app.

Here is what my main class looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: "/someroute"
      onGenerateRoute: MyRouteManager.generateRoute
    );
  }
```

I tried to follow [that example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069641/how-to-overlay-a-widget-on-top-of-a-flutter-app), but my problem is that I use named routes in my app, and I don't know how to overlay a widget above my entire app in that case.

I also tried the [overlay_screen plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_screen), but it has some bugs and does not allow the user to interact with the screen below the overlay screen.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: This question deserves lot of attention!!

Answer (score -5):

try this out:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/name_of_your_second_page');
```